# Change module's description from another module

Tags: 7, hooks

How can I change a description of a module from my custom module or how can I override `hook_process`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alter a module's information through [`hook_system_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_system_info_alter/7.x). For example to change the description of the Views module:

```
function MYMODULE_system_info_alter(&$info, $file, $type) {
  $info['views']['description'] = 'Something else';
}
```